# React native usestate blocks Animation?

Tags: react-native, animation

I am working on a small project with swipeable cards, using PanResponder from react-native.

In the onPanResponderRelease function the card automaticly swipes off the screen if the card is close to the edge, see the gif, pretty straightforward.

[image: normal behavior]

However, if I add a state change right before the Animated.timing starts, it is laggy. The lag comes exactly when I release my finger from the screen, and the Animated.timing starts. It stops for a moment. See the gif.

[image: laggy behavior]

I attach the code block too, I added the state change to row 27, marked.

```html
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Animated, Dimensions, PanResponder, View } from "react-native";
import UserOverview from "./UserOverview";

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const CARD_OUT = SCREEN_WIDTH * 1.4;
const FLING_OUT_X = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2.5;

export default CardSwiper = ({ cards }) => {
  const swipe = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [visibleCardsState, setVisibleCardsState] = useState(cards || []);
  const [pointerEventDisabled, setPointerEventDisabled] = useState("");

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
      return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > Math.abs(gestureState.dy);
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (e, { dx }) => {
      // 1: sentido horário | -1: sentido anti-horário
      swipe.setValue(dx);
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (e, { dx, vx }) => {
      const direction = Math.sign(dx);
      const userAction = Math.abs(dx) > FLING_OUT_X;

      if (userAction) {
        setPointerEventDisabled(true); // ******** THIS ROW IS CAUSING THE LAG
        Animated.timing(swipe, {
          toValue: direction * CARD_OUT,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start(() => {
          // remove swiped card from the array
          setVisibleCardsState((prevState) => [...prevState].slice(1));
          // resetting animated values
          swipe.setValue(0);
          setPointerEventDisabled(false);
        });
      } else {
        Animated.spring(swipe, {
          friction: 5,
          toValue: 0,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      }
    },
  });

  const rotate = swipe.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2],
    outputRange: ["10deg", "0deg", "-10deg"],
  });

  const animatedCardStyle = {
    transform: [{ translateX: swipe }, { rotate: rotate }],
  };

  return (
    visibleCardsState.length > 0 &&
    visibleCardsState
      .slice(0, 5)
      .map((card, idx) => {
        const isTopCard = idx === 0;
        const panHandlers = isTopCard ? panResponder.panHandlers : {};

        return (
          <Animated.View
            pointerEvents={pointerEventDisabled ? "none" : "auto"}
            key={idx}
            {...panHandlers}
            style={[
              isTopCard && animatedCardStyle,
              {
                position: "absolute",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                bottom: 0,
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
              },
            ]}
          >
            <UserOverview data={card} />
          </Animated.View>
        );
      })
      .reverse()
  );
};
```

I put that function there for a reason. I need to call it right before the animation starts. How can I do that without this lag? How to start parallel? Or maybe is there a way to call this function DURING the animation running? It's too late after it finished.

Comment: Can you might useRef instead of useState, this should prevent unnecessary rerender